# How to open experiments tab in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, livereload

I have watched Paul Irish's talk on developer workflow. There he opens a tab in chrome developer tools called experiments. Can somebody please tell me how how to get to it and wether I should download some sort of extention first?

---

The particular experiment that I want to be able to use is the support for sass, because the LiveReload app does not work on my computer. Can somebody, please advise some other app?

Comment: I think what you are after is `chrome://flags/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments, and click Enable.